# How do I add HTML attributes to a Razor HtmlHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a general question about some Razor Syntax I keep finding in a project I am working on...

One of the main helpers being used is: `@Html.InputFor`

They then insert some Lambda for example: `@Html.InputFor(_ => _.User)`

My question is, how do I work with this helper (I couldn't find any details via a google search) i.e adding attributes like custom css classes?

Is there a better helper I should be using? (I am new to Razor)

Comment: Can you not `Go To Definition` in Visual Studio to find out more?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think you mean [`@Html.TextBoxFor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). That extension method can be found in the `InputExtensions` class.

How to attach an attribute to it? Use the `htmlAttributes` property:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.User, htmlAttributes : new { @class = "cssclass" } )
```

Comment: My project actually uses "InputFor", could this be some custom helper which is define somewhere in my project?

Comment: @user3371361: Press F12 and you will find out.

Comment: "cannot navigate to 'InputFor'"?

Comment: My thoughts too. There must be a `using` that includes the extension method. Try to delete one you don't know of and see if it gives an error on that line.

Answer (score 2):

I might be wrong, but i don't think InputFor is a standard MVC helper.  Usually you would use either `Html.EditorFor()` and define an editor template or for say a string input a `Html.TextBoxFor()` where you can pass html attributes

e.g. `Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.User, new { @class="form-control" })`

the `@class` being necessary as class is a c# keyword

Answer (score 1):

It can be an custom Extension Method applied for `HtmlHelper` object. Just Have look in the project in a static class.

This [link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs) will be very helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

`HtmlHelper` class is used to create common html controls on page.There is no `InputFor` extended method.

Ex: Below will create text box for `model.Name` property.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
```

See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) for more details.